# Открытие нового окна PyQt5 по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

У меня я есть три файла. Два это интерфейс окон, а третий это главный файл, в котором я хочу сделать действия для всех кнопок.

**main.py**

```
from first_menu import *
from second_menu import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FirstMenu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FirstMenu()
    ui.setupUi(FirstMenu)
    FirstMenu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**first_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_first_menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, first_menu):
        first_menu.setObjectName("first_menu")
        first_menu.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(first_menu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        first_menu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(first_menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(first_menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, first_menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        first_menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("first_menu", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("first_menu", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("first_menu", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    first_menu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_first_menu()
    ui.setupUi(first_menu)
    first_menu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**second_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_second_menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, second_menu):
        second_menu.setObjectName("second_menu")
        second_menu.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(second_menu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        second_menu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(second_menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second_menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, second_menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second_menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("second_menu", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("second_menu", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("second_menu", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    second_menu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_second_menu()
    ui.setupUi(second_menu)
    second_menu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вопрос: как мне сделать так чтобы в 3 файле хранился код функционала кнопок?

Comment: Предоставьте содержимое трех модулей, о которых вы упомянули и лучше расскажите что вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку pushButton открывалось окно second_menu. Как это сделать я знаю, но как сделать так что бы функциональный код кнопки находился в первом файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать. Возможный вариант задуманного вами может выглядеть так:

**q1418513_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from q1418513_first_menu import Ui_first_menu
from q1418513_second_menu import Ui_second_menu


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_second_menu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.resize(300, 300)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_first_menu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.pushButton.setText('Открыть второе окно.')
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go_second_menu)
        
        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow()
        
    def go_second_menu(self, state):
        if state:
            self.secondWindow.show()
            self.pushButton.setText('Закрыть второе окно.')
        else:
            self.secondWindow.hide()
            self.pushButton.setText('Открыть второе окно.')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1418513_first_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_first_menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, first_menu):
        first_menu.setObjectName("first_menu")
        first_menu.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(first_menu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        
        first_menu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(first_menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(first_menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, first_menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        first_menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("first_menu", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("first_menu", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("first_menu", "PushButton"))
```

**q1418513_second_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_second_menu(object):
    def setupUi(self, second_menu):
        second_menu.setObjectName("second_menu")
        second_menu.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(second_menu)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        
        second_menu.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(second_menu)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second_menu)

    def retranslateUi(self, second_menu):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second_menu.setWindowTitle(_translate("second_menu", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("second_menu", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("second_menu", "TextLabel"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, похоже вы правильно меня поняли

Comment: @ЕгорРыжов Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour